# php exec not working properly on remote server

Tags: php

php functions like exec and shell_exec work fine on localhost but it doesn't work properly on remote host.

```
$output = shell_exec('dir');

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

This code gives output in localhost but not at remote server.
Any Clue?

Comment: Asking questions with examples out of context doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of php commands are usually disabled on remote web servers. If you really want them to works, you should use a dedicated server and configure it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`dir` command is in windows system, so is your remote server a windows server too?

Even it is a windows server, the configure may be different from your local machine that disables `shell_exec`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/glob or http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php
Executing `dir` or `ls` makes no sense at all, to me.

Comment: problem is not about dir command but about exec()and shell_exec() functions

Comment: Look into the error log then. But I guess it's about: "I don't have permission to use system calls on my webspace and the sysadmin disabled these functions at system level in the php.ini."